# TOMCAT_OPTS, environment variable and System.getEnv()

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, environment-variables

I use tomcat and I want to get an environment variable in my java code.

To set an environment variable, I use this bash command :

```
export TOMCAT_OPTS=-Dmy.var=foo
```

After it I start tomcat

```
./startup.sh (in bin folder of tomcat)
```

In my java code, I try to get this variable :

```
System.getEnv("my.var")
```

But it returns NULL.

How can I do that ?

I precise that if I use maven to launch tomcat and use eclipse environment tab, the variable is found ! But I need to launch tomcat like above in production mode.

EDIT: when using export MY_VAR directly it runs in local but not on my server...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found a config file named tomcat6.conf in CATALINA_HOME.
I add export my.var=foo to the end of file and System.getenv("my.var") now returns the value...

Nightmare...

Comment: If it means anything, thanks to your enduring that nightmare, now I and others wandering this trail won't have to :)

Answer (score 20):

`System.getEnv` returns environment variables like PATH or, in your example, TOMCAT_OPTS).

When you invoke Java with `-Dfoo=bar`, you don't set an environment variable : you pass a system property. Use `System.getProperty` to get the value of foo.

Comment: thanks, but how can I specify environment variable to Tomcat  instead ?

Comment: To create an environment variable : export FOO=BAR. To read an environment variable : System.getenv("FOO"). To pass a system property to a Java application : java -Dfoo=bar my.java.App. To read a system property : System.getProperty("foo"). To pass a system property to Tomcat : export TOMCAT_OPTS=-Dfoo=bar. To read the system property in your web app : System.getProperty("foo").

Comment: Seems that on my server, the variable can not be read (return null). In local, all runs perfectly. What can it be ?

Answer (score 13):

if you are using tomcat7 and unbuntu os, you can edit the /etc/default/tomcat7 file,
just add a line of yourvar=yourvalue will do that.

like below:

```
# Run Tomcat as this user ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use the
# default of tomcat7.
TOMCAT7_USER=tomcat7

# Run Tomcat as this group ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use
# the default of tomcat7.
TOMCAT7_GROUP=tomcat7

IM4JAVA_TOOLPATH=/usr/local/bin/

# The home directory of the Java development kit (JDK). You need at least
# JDK version 1.5. If JAVA_HOME is not set, some common directories for
# OpenJDK, the Sun JDK, and various J2SE 1.5 versions are tried.
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-6-jdk

# You may pass JVM startup parameters to Java here. If unset, the default
# options will be: -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
# 
# Use "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" to enable the CMS garbage collector (improved
# response time). If you use that option and you run Tomcat on a machine with
# exactly one CPU chip that contains one or two cores, you should also add
# the "-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode" option.
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2048m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

Comment: [For Ubuntu OS] This needs to be higher. Simplest, most consistent way to set environment variables that tomcat can read

Comment: @Siddharth see Nikita Bosik 's answer :) happy coding

Answer (score 3):

There's a config file for tomcat, by default located at `/dev/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf` I believe (look in /etc/init.d/tomcat to see what the value of "TOMCAT_CFG" is. This is "sourced" `.` in this file (`. $TOMCAT_CFG`) before tomcat is started (or stopped, restarted, etc), so if you add the line:

```
MY_VAR=somevalue
```

That should be available to your java application.

I know this is an old question, but maybe it will be useful to someone else :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this post has already been answered 1 year ago ! And the solution you give is already explained into the accepted answer...

Comment: Oh yeah. Good point :) I didn't notice that one as it's so short (in spite of the tick (I blame the advert above it :P))

Answer (score 3):

### For Tomcat7 + Ubuntu:

**Set:**

1. Open `/etc/default/tomcat7` file
2. Add line `somekey=value`

   *Note: variable's name can't contain dots.*
3. Restart Tomcat: `service tomcat7 restart`

**Read:**

`System.getenv("somekey");`

Comment: this answer is more concise and readable than my answer, I like it :)

Answer (score 3):

in **Tomcat8** installed by just unpacking the archive, there is a file called "**catalina.properties**"

You can introduce environment variables in this file by just adding

```
my.special.variable=some_value
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set environment variable in tomcat to get in through **getEnv**, use **setenv**.

I.e. in tomcat/bin you have (or should create) `setenv.sh` (or `setenv.bat` for шindoшs) and define

```
my.var=FOO
OTHERVAR=BOO
```

prepending it with `set` for шindoшs.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have explained to me that you are using yum based installation (which suggest a Red Hat distro derivatives), if you are running your Tomcat as daemon, then you'll need to set your "export TOMCAT_OPTS=..." command in you /etc/profile (for global scope), or add it in your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file at the home of the user who starts the Tomcat instance.

Comment: It's a standard installation on Amazon EC2 linux machine with "yum install tomcat6". And using CATALINA_OPTS does not run too :(

Comment: another question, do you run the bash "export" command from a script different from the one that runs tomcat?

Comment: setting the export in bash_provile or bashrc does not run but I've found a solution (see my anwser). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Tomcat on Eclipse IDE? Then you just need follow this steps:

1. Double click on tomcat server
2. Open launch configuration
3. Environment
4. New (Name / Value)