# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring, amazon-ec2, spring-el

Config in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/jdbc-${WEB_ENVIRONMENT}.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:/settings-${WEB_ENVIRONMENT}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"></property>
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

I have set the environment variable in both my user's & root's .bashrc file like so

```
export WEB_ENVIRONMENT=prod
```

On Starting tomcat I'm getting the error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jdbc-${WEB_ENVIRONMENT}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I also tried it this way:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/jdbc-#{T(java.lang.System).getenv('WEB_ENVIRONMENT')}.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:/settings-#{T(java.lang.System).getenv('WEB_ENVIRONMENT')}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"></property>
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

This time I get the error

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jdbc-.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Which means that SpEL is functional inside the applicationContext.xml but not able to fetch variables from the System environment.

To check if value is correctly set I ran `echo ${WEB_ENVIRONMENT}` and it correctly returns the value. So, to check if java is able to fetch the value from the environment I ran

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getenv("WEB_ENVIRONMENT"));
    }

}
```

This also correctly returned "prod"

Both version run in Windows, **but do not in Amazon EC2's Linux AMI**.

What should I try next to get it to work?

Comment: Also note, `#{systemProperties['WEB_ENVIRONMENT']}` doesn't work either

Comment: How are you starting tomcat in EC2?

Comment: sudo service tomcat7 start. Though would prefer to have it set in the environment rather than passing -D arguments

Comment: And which user is running tomcat (look for the java processing in `ps auxwww`)?  I think that the env var isn't picked up, e.g. if bash isn't used to start tomcat or a different user is running tomcat.

Comment: tomcat is also installed as a service with runs on start up. Somehow `ps auxwww` shows tomcat as the user running tomcat! I'm a noob at linux so dunno what that means..

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115339/tomcat-opts-environment-variable-and-system-getenv)

Comment: when the tomcat is running as user tomcat, it doesn't read your .bashrc, have a look at the tomcat config (catalina.sh, ...) and add your env there

Comment: @VarunAchar: or add it to /etc/profile which adds the env variable globally, though personally I would go with Arne's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first attempt you have a hen and egg problem, I think. You want to configure the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` using values that need to be replaced with properties. This wont work!

The SpEL approach should work, I just tried a similar config on my mac (UNIX like system) with a value listed by `printenv` on the shell (`USER`). The result is as expected:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [settings-arne.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

You can set the environment variable as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115339/tomcat-opts-environment-variable-and-system-getenv). Another way is to add the variable to add it to /etc/profile which adds the env variable globally. The former is preferred.

Comment: Hmm.. You think it's something to do with the Linux distribution on the EC2 instance?

Comment: @VarunAchar: Do you have the same Tomcat Version lokal and remote? And the same configuration (context.xml, ...)?

Comment: It's the stock tomcat configuration both places. Same version

Answer (score 1):

Few options that I know,

1. Try to set it as VM Arguments when you start the application.
   i.e. `-DWEB_ENVIRONMENT=prod`
2. In case of Tomcat you can set it in `JAVA_OPTS` see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7738884/876142) to find out how to achieve that.
3. In my own project I set my environment variable value in `catalina.properties` at very end by putting `-Druntime_env=dev`.

Comment: Where's the catalina.sh file located? I can't seem to find it in the ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin folder.

Comment: Personal suggestion, dont edit catalina.sh rather update catalina.propertis under ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf