# UrlMapping to static files in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, url-mapping

I want to map the static files sitemap.xml and robots.txt which a located in my web-app directory. The urls should be as follows:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml 
http://www.mydomain.com/robots.txt
```

How do I have to set the url mapping to make these routes work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use this mapping for `robots.txt`:

```
"/robots.txt" (view: "/robots")
```

And then have a `grails-app/views/robots.gsp` that contains the content for `robots.txt`. This way I can use `<g:if env="...">` to easily have different content for different environments.

In order for this to work for a ".xml" extension, you need to change the [Content Negotiation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#contentNegotiation) config.

```
grails.mime.file.extensions = false // disables the parsing of file extensions from URLs into the request format
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for robots, but not for sitemap.xml how would you do that?

Comment: Does this solution has any any side effects?

Comment: Automatic content negotiation based on file extensions won't happen

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way is to tell grails to ignore them in `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static excludes = ['/robots.txt', '/sitemap.xml']

    static mappings = {
        // normal mappings here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer more accurately represents what the OP requested, although the selected answer provides a working alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be helpful to to set up a nofollow to your Staging environment if you are using one. Not sure if there is a use case to having a staging site indexed.... so if you agree you may be able to use these steps to help block that.

If you are using Tomcat, set an environment variable such as ***NOFOLLOW=true*** --> see here for example: [TOMCAT_OPTS, environment variable and System.getEnv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115339/tomcat-opts-environment-variable-and-system-getenv)

Next as mentioned by @doelleri set the urlMappings

**UrlMappings**

```
//Robots.txt
"/robots.txt"(controller: 'robots', action:'robots')
```

Then use your robotsController to detect the environment variable you set on your staging tomcat.

**RobotsController**

```
def robots() {
    if (System.getenv('NOFOLLOW') == 'true') {
        def text = "User-agent: *\n" +
            "Disallow: /cgi-bin/ \n" +
            "Disallow: /tmp/ \n" +
            "Disallow: /junk/ \n" +
            "Disallow: /admin/ \n" +
            "Crawl-delay: 5 \n" +
            "Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml"

        render(text: text, contentType: "text/plain", encoding: "UTF-8")
    } else {
        render(status: 404, text: 'Failed to load robots.txt')
    }
}
```

**robots.gsp**

```
<%-- Content rendered from controller -> so leave blank :) --%>
```