# launcher.gcr.io/google/jenkins2 does not draw chart

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using `launcher.gcr.io/google/jenkins2` to run jenkins in gcp kubernetes engine.

Everything seems ok except that I get `Could not initialize class org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart` error for every chart that jenkins attempt to draw. I googled the error and almost everyone solves that with adding `-Djava.awt.headless=true`. As you can guess I already tried that and it does not work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other possible solution/workaround is seen in [JENKINS issue 39636](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39636):

> I installed `libxext6 libxrender1 fontconfig libfontconfig` but it didn't help. After that I also installed `libjfreechart-java` but I still have the same problem.
>
> Commenting out the `assistive_technologies` line in `/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties` solved it.

You can see that recommendation in [tianon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433558/tianon)'s  [comment of that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841269/performance-graphs-on-jenkins-causing-could-not-initialize-class-org-jfree-char#comment76900079_41428450):

> In my case it ended up being [bugs.debian.org/798794](https://bugs.debian.org/798794) (from "[Assistive technology not found error while building `aprof-plot`](https://askubuntu.com/a/723503/5470)").
> Adding "`RUN sed -i 's/^assistive_technologies=/#&/' /etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties`" to my `Dockerfile` fixed it. :)

Comment: this did it. Thanks