# Get system variable inside servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, servlets, environment-variables

I am having this very weird issue.

I have one servlet in which I want to access one system variable.

As per [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) documentation I have set my environment variable in `/etc/environment` as

```
TEMP=Temp.something
```

Now when I do `printenv TEMP` I get

```
Temp.something
```

Also I have wrote simple program like this

```
public class env {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String test = System.getProperty("TEMP");
                System.out.println(test);
        }
}
```

which outputs

```
Temp.something
```

Now, I have wrote one servlet which is deployed on tomcat on the same machine, which has this statement

```
System.out.println("Config : " + System.getenv("TEMP"));
```

This always prints `null`.
I'm pretty new to servlets. Is something I'm missing?

Comment: Have a look at whole thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115339/tomcat-opts-environment-variable-and-system-getenv

Comment: That seem to work out. I had to make entry inside `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make entry inside `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh`

```
TEMP=Temp.something
```

I'm not sure why do I had to do this. When I say get system environment variable it should get me system variable :(